# Error when trying to highlight border color in Vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```css
.input-section {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 359px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 45px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #b1b8c9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="fullname" 
  id="fullname" 
  v-model="fullname"
  v-model.trim="$v.fullname.$model" 
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.fullname) }" 
  class="input-section" 
  v-on:keypress="isLetter($event)" 
  placeholder="Enter your name"
/>

<input 
  class="input-section label-set" 
  type="text" 
  id="mobile" 
  v-model="mobile" 
  v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model" 
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }"
  placeholder="Enter your mobile number" 
  v-on:keypress="isMobile($event)"
/>
```

How to highlight border color of input, if no data enterd, That is user without entering fullname try to enter mobile number then border of fullname should be in red color.

Can we change border color based on :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.fullname) }"

Comment: Not sure what it actually does but you may probably not want to have 2 `v-model` on the same HTML element.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Comment: @kissu, I have tried the code but it's not working. If possible can u please give me a codesandbox link. with the above provided code. So that it will be really helpful.

Comment: Usually, the OP does that kind of thing lol. Making the effort of formatting your question, answering it and hosting a solution is something that I sometimes do (a lot of work huh ?) but here, I do not have your whole code so I'd rather prefer if you make this effort.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** have a method computed in a `:class`, meanwhile you can call a method on `@input` (`v-on:keypress` actually do not exist in VueJS), and use the result of a `computed` or `data` inside of you class.

Like this

```html
<input
  @input="validateStatus"
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': validEmail }"
>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    validEmail: false
  }
},
methods: {
  validateStatus(input) { // will be passed automatically from the template
    if (input.value === 'valid') { // your awesome validation
      this.validEmail = true
    } else {
      this.validEmail = false
    }
  }
}
```